# Set instance of an object depending of variable inside a class

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code inside a class called `Tramos`

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Agente As Dictionary
Private m_Pronostico As Dictionary
Property Get Pronosticos(ByVal Key As String) As Pronosticos
    With m_Pronostico
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Pronosticos
    End With
    Set Pronosticos = m_Pronostico(Key)
End Property
Property Get Agentes(ByVal Key As Integer) As Agentes
    With m_Agente
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Agentes
    End With
    Set Agentes = m_Agente(Key)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Agente = New Dictionary
    If Not Programaciones Then Set m_Pronostico = New Dictionary
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_Agente = Nothing
    If Not Programaciones Then Set m_Pronostico = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get Keys() As Variant
    Keys = m_Agente.Keys
End Property
Public Property Get PronosKeys() As Variant
    PronosKeys = m_Pronostico.Keys
End Property
```

I have a global variable called `Programaciones`, if its `True` then the class wont set the `m_Pronostico`, I did this because I was experiencing memory problems when working with a lot of instances of this class. The problem comes that when this object is not set, this will most likely throw errors when debugging `Object Required` I assume because of the `PronosKeys` property.

Is there any way to set an object inside a class depending of a variable which won't throw errors if I have properties referencing the object  I didn't set?

Comment: You can safely call `Set m_Pronostico = Nothing` without checking the condition even if the object is nothing.

Comment: Also, I would instantiate the dictionary to avoid errors if you try to access it from the property.

Comment: @KostasK. If I instantiate the dictionary my memory consumption goes way up and I could encounter the out of memory error... Thats why I'm trying to optimize the memory management. Instantiating dictionaries that I won't use (there) hits my performance... Already did the tests and I could get up to 400MB of extra memory used because of this.

Comment: I don't think an empty dictionary consumes that much memory. Anyway, if that's the case then you probably need to redesign your solution. You should not have a property pointing to a null object.

Comment: Both objects follow the same path, thought I need one for some procedures and I need the other one for some other procedures. How would I redesign this without duplicating all my classes @KostasK.?